# SVG not fully rendered in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, svg

I was trying to load some SVG for point features, but some of the SVG symbols were partially rendered.

Someone from the community suggested that the SVG with too large/small aspect ratio would cause this problem. However, I trust there should be a way to solve this problem by optimizing SLD code.

Here is my SLD:

```
<se:FeatureTypeStyle>
<se:Rule>
    <se:Name>55052222</se:Name>
    <!--ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fcode</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>55012104</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Filter-->
        <se:MaxScaleDenominator>20000.0</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
                <se:ExternalGraphic>
                    <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="55052222.svg" />
                    <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
                </se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:Size>18</se:Size>
                <se:Rotation>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>orientation</ogc:PropertyName>
                </se:Rotation>
            </se:Graphic>
        </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

GeoServer version is 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no way to solve it at the SLD level.

You should check carefully the bounding boxes declared in the SVG itself. Or look into contributing a code change that does not trust the view bbox of the SVG, but rather walks into the tree of elements and computes an overall bounding box of the actual geometries.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for helping!
Can you be more specific about which property I should edit for svg file?
One of the svg be like:
<svg version="1.1" id="layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 38.6 4.5"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 38.6 4.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FF0000;}
</style>

Comment: Check the viewBox... is it as big enough to contain all geometries inside the SVG?